Multiple integral with laplace operator
My question comes from the academic paper called Stable solutions of $-\Delta u= f(u)$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$ by L. Dupaigne and A.Farina. I don't understand how to go from the first expression with one brace to the second with another brace.
Assume $\Omega$ is a an arbitrary open set in $\mathbb{R}^N$. Let $u\in C^{2}(\Omega)$ with $u\geq 0 $ satisfy
\begin{equation}
    -\Delta u \leq f(u) \quad \text{in}\;\Omega   
 \end{equation}
Let $\psi\in C^{1}_{c}(\Omega)$ , $\phi\in W^{1,\infty}_{loc}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ denote a convex function and $\eta\in C^{1}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^N)$. Let
\begin{equation*}
    \psi(u)=\int_{0}^{u}\left( \phi^{\prime} \right)^2 (t)dt
  \end{equation*}
Let $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^{+})$ is nondecreasing convex, $f>0$ in $\mathbb{R}^{*}_{+}$. and $K(u)=\int_0^u \psi(s) d s$.
Multiply by $\psi(u) \eta^2$ and integrate by parts:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{\Omega} \nabla u \nabla\left(\psi(u) \eta^2\right) d x & \leq \int_{\Omega} f(u) \psi(u) \eta^2 d x, \\
\int_{\Omega} \phi^{\prime}(u)^2|\nabla u|^2 \eta^2 d x + \underbrace{\int_{\Omega} \psi(u) \nabla u \nabla \eta^2 d x} & \leq \int_{\Omega} f(u) \psi(u) \eta^2 d x, \\
\int_{\Omega} \phi^{\prime}(u)^2|\nabla u|^2 \eta^2 d x - \underbrace{\int_{\Omega} K(u) \Delta \eta^2 d x }& \leq \int_{\Omega} f(u) \psi(u) \eta^2 d x,
\end{aligned}
$$
